# How do you force shutdown a unresponsive VM with VMWare with a IOS host?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-fusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgavN.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgavN.jpg)I have windows 10 running on VMWare Fusion on my MacBook pro. I've used it without problem for the past year then today in my class the screen just went black. I cant even see the mouse I scrolled my mouse to the top and was able to get the mac top task bar and was able to close out of the VM and it was suspended but it wont let me shut it down. Anyone know the process I need to take to do this? I know I could always shut the mac down and entirely and restart but don't want to risk damaging the windows image. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Maybe this could work, I used it a few times as well.

Comment: Sadly that option is shadowed out on mine meaning its not available for some reason.

Comment: I ran force shutdown through mac and it killed VMWare but when I reopened it and the Image was still suspended. so I hard reset the Mac and upon reboot the image was still suspended and not shutdown.

Comment: @zuk i believe VM has a forum, maybe you could ask there as well. I have no clue.

Comment: I appreciate your help I contacted their support and they told me without registration of the license they cant help me i went to register my license and when i tried my license came back invalid lol. so will have to try and call their number once i get out of class. Thanks again.